# Wordpress backend too slow, even after wiping out all expired transient and sessions in database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It seems like my issue has not been here before, so I have created a new thread.

We have an e-commerce website and currently the back end is pretty slow. I did delete all the expired transient and session in database (before it was 1.2 GB but now is 200 MB). But the issue is that the admin site still slow and data is growing fast.

We have a lot of plugins and I am not sure if they are involved in this problem. We are using Wordpress version 4.2.2 and WooCommerce version 2.3.8, so I am thinking about upgrading them to latest versions, to make the admin site working faster as possible.

I hope that someone can tell me how to fix this issue. We struggle with this issue for a while.

Here are our configuration details (WooCommerce system status):

```html
### WordPress Environment ###

WP Version: 4.2.2
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 200 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
Language: en_US

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 5.6.21
PHP Post Max Size: 20 MB
PHP Time Limit: 120
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.6.29
Max Upload Size: 20 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: 
fsockopen/cURL: 
SoapClient: 
DOMDocument: 
GZip: 
Remote Post: 
Remote Get: 

### Server Locale ###

decimal_point: .
thousands_sep: N/A
mon_decimal_point: N/A
mon_thousands_sep: N/A

### Active Plugins (32) ###

Extension Works Framework: by Extension Works – 1.9.1
WooCommerce ANZ eGate: by Extension Works – 1.3.5
AdWords Conversion Tracking Code: by kcseopro – 1.0
Breadcrumb NavXT: by John Havlik – 5.2.0
Calculated Fields Form: by CodePeople.net – 1.0.83
Checkout Address Suggestion And Autocomplete For Woocommerce: by Magerips – 1.3
Contact Form 7: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 4.1.2
Excel-Like Product Manager for WooCommerce and WP E-commerce: by Holest Engineering – 1.4.12
Google Analytics by Yoast: by Team Yoast – 5.4.2
WPBakery Visual Composer: by Michael M - WPBakery.com – 4.4.4
Limit Login Attempts: by Johan Eenfeldt – 1.7.1
Really Simple CAPTCHA: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 1.8.0.1
Regenerate Thumbnails: by Viper007Bond – 2.2.4
Relevanssi: by Mikko Saari – 3.5.2
Optimize Database after Deleting Revisions: by CAGE Web Design | Rolf van Gelder
Eindhoven
The Netherlands – 4.1.5

Search By SKU - for Woocommerce: by Matthew Lawson – 0.6.1
Simple 301 Redirects: by Scott Nellé – 1.06
OXY Shortcodes: by Smartdatasoft – 1.0
Woocommerce Custom Tabs: by WebshopLogic – 1.0.16
WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing: by Lucas Stark – 2.10.11 – 2.11.0 is available
WooCommerce Inecom Integration: by OPMC – 1.0.0
WooCommerce Jetpack: by Algoritmika Ltd – 2.2.0
Woocommerce Mailchimp Discount: by Magnigenie – 1.8.1
WooCommerce Points and Rewards: by WooThemes – 1.4.1
WooCommerce Sequential Order Numbers Pro: by WooThemes / SkyVerge – 1.8.0 – 1.10.0 is available
WooCommerce Table Rate Shipping: by Mike Jolley – 2.9.2
WooCommerce: by WooThemes – 2.3.8
WooSidebars: by WooThemes – 1.4.2
WooThemes Helper: by WooThemes – 1.5.9
WordPress SEO: by Team Yoast – 2.1.1
WP Super Cache: by Automattic – 1.4.7
Zopim Widget: by Zopim – 1.3.7

### Settings ###

API Enabled: 
Taxes Enabled: 
Shipping Enabled: 
Force SSL: 
Currency: AUD ($)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2

### WC Pages ###

Shop Base: #6 - /shop/
Cart: #7 - /cart/
Checkout: #8 - /checkout/
My Account: #9 - /my-account/

### Taxonomies ###

Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)


### Theme ###

Name: Oxygen Child Theme
Version: 1.0.0
Author URL: 
Child Theme: 
Parent Theme Name: 
Parent Theme Version: 
Parent Theme Author URL: 
WooCommerce Support: 

### Templates ###

Overrides: oxy/woocommerce/archive-product.php
oxy/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php
oxy/woocommerce/content-product.php
oxy/woocommerce/content-product_cat.php
oxy/woocommerce/content-single-product.php
oxy-child/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
oxy-child/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php
oxy-child/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php
oxy-child/woocommerce/emails/plain/admin-new-order.php
oxy/woocommerce/loop/orderby.php
oxy/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php
oxy/woocommerce/loop/price.php
oxy/woocommerce/loop/sale-flash.php
oxy/woocommerce/loop/sorting.php
oxy/woocommerce/loop-shop.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/breadcrumb.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/errors.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/form-login.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/messages.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/sidebar.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/wrapper-end.php
oxy/woocommerce/shop/wrapper-start.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/external.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/price.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/related.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/review.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/sale-flash.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/share.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/tabs.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/title.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product/up-sells.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php
oxy/woocommerce/single-product.php
oxy/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php
oxy/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_tag.php
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec,

Thanks for your reply, I could not upload the system status as the text limitation. Do you know any way I can upload more than 550 characters?

By the way, do you think increase the memory limit can become a risk of network security? the host supplier warn me that.

Comment: Hi I did update my question, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: What details you need?

Comment: Is it a shared hosting? what kind of hosting (available specs)? Looking to your woocommerce details config try to update 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' to '512M' or '1024M'  (to the maximum value that you can have regarding your hosting possibilities. Also It could be useful to update Wordpress and plugins to last versions (one exception for Yoast SEO: try to get version 2.3.5 but not version 3.X.X.

Comment: Hi @@LoicTheAztec, our hosting is the private one so it is pretty sophisticated in term of speed. I did increase the wp_max_memory_limit but the site is not fast as it should be. IS there any other way to improve the speed?

By the way, the table wp_options grow pretty fast as it includes transition ans session. Do you know how to slow down this growing process.

Comment: You will need to update everything, Wordpress and all plugins, except Yoast SEO (find version 2.3.5 but not version 3 and above) and to debug because there is a lot of changes. To avoid transient sessions growing too much, you have to do a regular maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am thinking about this as well. I will update this issue after upgrading most of the site. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Please check by upgrading WordPress, Plugin and themes to the latest    version.  
Remove all unwanted plugins and themes 
Optimize your images    ,database, css and js by using htaccess

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We are thinking upgrading woocommerce and wordpress to see how the speed going.

Comment: Ok great..that is really a nice move..

Answer (score 0):

The versions of the plugins are not the reason the admin runs slowly, in my opinion. If your WordPress is 4.2.2, I'm guessing the plugins are compatible with the platform.

Did you test the speed, when all the plugins are deactivated? You can do that and then activate the plugins one by one to see which one is slowing the admin down.

Comment: Hi Maie M,

Thanks for your suggestion, I did try deactivate all the plugin and the site will become really fast. But we rely on all the plugins to operate all  functions of our site so it is pretty hard for us to the replace the old ones which harm the performance of our Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

just want to have an update for this issue. Our website got faster after I upgraded woocommerce and wordpress to the latest version. I think my problem is the combination of version of wordpress/woocommerce and the database in term of transient and session expiration. So finally the speed gets back to normal. I hope some one else got this issue can reference my case and speed up their website both fron end and back end.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how many render-blocking requests your website has. Plugins can add a lot of scripts to your website.

I'd suggest using some form of cacheing and also enable Gzipping too.